# How do I correctly use a ternary operator in React

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm fetching data from an API which, depending on the item clicked on my webpage, may or may not have JSON data in the 'description' key. I'm trying to set up a ternary operator so that if there is data present in 'description' it should display that data, and if not it should display 'No description'. This is all working fine when there is data in description (condition is true), but if there isn't (condition is false) the page breaks.

Is there any reason why this ternary operator isn't working?

```
<div id="popup">
  <h2>{selectedEvent.name}</h2>
  {selectedEvent.descriptions[0].description ? (
  <p>{selectedEvent.descriptions[0].description}</p>
    ) : <p>No description</p>
}
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: When the page breaks, what is the error message? This is the correct way to use a ternary, so something else is going wrong.

Comment: What does your selectedEvent object look like when the condition is false?

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, I figured it out. I just had to change the condition to - 

selectedEvent.descriptions[0] removing the .description

Answer (score 2):

Always check for keys inside objects

```
  const description = electedEvent.descriptions[0];
  return (
   <div id="popup">
    <h2>{selectedEvent.name}</h2>
     {description && description.description ? (
       <p>{description.description}</p>
     ) : <p>No description</p>
    }
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example above:

```
 function getFee(isLoyalMember) {
      return (isLoyalMember ? '$2.00' : '$10.00'); // here the first output gets 
                                                  //returned if member is not 
                                                 //loyal. If customer is loyal, we 
                                                //return $10.00 instead.
    }
```

Let us console log that and see the output:

```
    console.log(getFee(true));
    // expected output: "$2.00"

    console.log(getFee(false));
    // expected output: "$10.00"

    console.log(getFee(1));
    // expected output: "$2.00"
```

To make yours work. Do the following:

```
  const description = electedEvent.descriptions[0];
  return (
   <div id="popup">
    <h2>{selectedEvent.name}</h2>
     {description && description.description ? (
       <p>{description.description}</p>
     ) : <p>No description</p>
    }
   </div>
)
```